# WiX installer not creating registry key

Tags: wix, registry

Short version of question - what might be preventing my WiX built installer from creating a registry key (or including the component that creates it)?

Longer version:
Using the following piece of code, I created a WiX-built installer that created a registry key:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="RegistrySetup" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="MyCompany" UpgradeCode="b56de3e6-b630-4763-886e-fe14f5d571ae">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="RegistrySetup" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>
    </Product>

    <Fragment>
        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="RegistrySetup" />
            </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
            <Component Id="RegistryEntries" Guid="B0A06192-89B4-4D23-B983-EDB18BCEE2C9"> 
                <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\MyCompany\MyProduct">
                    <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Version" Value="[ProductVersion]" KeyPath="yes"/>
                </RegistryKey>
            </Component> 
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

and that worked just fine.  I have another, more complex install to which I'd like to add the same registry key, so I figured that the only thing I need to do is take the `<Component>` portion, copy that, enclose it in a `<DirectoryRef>`, change the guid, and add the Component's Id to the list of components which are installed as part of the program's feature, something like the following:

```
<Product>
    ...
    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLDIR">
        <Component Id="RegistryEntries" Guid="A0A06192-89B4-4D23-B983-EDB18BCEE2C9"> 
            <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\MyCompany\MyProduct">
                <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="Version" Value="[ProductVersion]" KeyPath="yes"/>
            </RegistryKey>
        </Component> 
    </DirectoryRef>
    ...
    <Feature Id="Complete" Title="MyProduct">
        <ComponentRef Id="RegistryEntries/>
        ...
    </Feature>
</Product>
```

However, when I do this and run the install, the registry key is not created.  Not only that, when I use Orca to look at the Windows installer database that gets compiled, the RegistryEntries component is not even part of the the installer - it's as if WiX has stripped it from the install for some reason.  I thought it might be something to do with installer bitness (32 or 64 bit) and tried all combinations of compiling the installer for x86 or x64 and setting Win64=yes or no on the Component and RegistryKey entries, but that didn't affect things....  Any idea what would cause the component not to be included?

Comment: besides the missing quote at the end of `<ComponentRef>` :), do you see any warnings during build? candle/light usually do not remove any components if they have been referenced somewhere ...